# JOLT specification to shift columns to the end of JSON

Tags: json, jolt

I am trying to write a spec to shift a few key in a json object to the very end of the object.

```
{
 "id": "12345",
 "timestamp": "2019-10-28 13:24:44.547", 
 "action": "notify",
 "name": "test"
}
```

to:

```
{
 "id": "12345",
 "action": "notify",
 "name": "test",
 "timestamp": "2019-10-28 13:24:44.547"
}
```

Appreciate any leads on how to go about doing this using JOLT.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is an answer, but I'm not so sure that Jolt keeps an order.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "id": "id",
      "action": "action",
      "name": "name",
      "timestamp": "timestamp"
    }
  }
]
```